# Cannot create migrations Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I want to work with Laravel, wanna no what all this hype is about.
Slowly, I have no patience left.
I tried make it working for weeks, now I finally did - but I seem to cannot be able to create migratons...

Creating itself is possible.
But when I type in

`php artisan migrate`

that errors occur:

> `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table
>   or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create
>   table`users`(`   id`int unsigned not null auto_increment primary
>   key,`name`varchar(255) not null,`email`varchar(255) not null,`
>   password`varchar(255) not null,`remember_token`varchar(100) null,`
>   created_at`timestamp null,`updated_at` tim   estamp null) default
>   character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists:
>   1050 Table 'users' already exists`

Is there anything I can do?
It is trying to migrate the wrong migrations...
Laravel is cool, but every 5 minutes there are some strange bugs (although I simply follow a tutorial...)

Comment: So, what's __unclear__ in message `Table 'users' already exists`?

Comment: I know it exists, but it is not the correct migration, no matter what I do, it tries to create the users table.

Comment: Migrations do what is written in their `up` function. Obviously your migrations try to create table __twice__.

Comment: No. I haven't even edited it, it is auto generated.

I hate this about Laravel, it never works :(

Comment: Then you're trying to migrate same file again? Why?

Comment: Have you added `down` function? Only then it works for such case

Comment: `php artisan migrate:rollback` Assuming you have rollback written in down method

Comment: Find the `migrations` file that creates the users table, and comment everything in the `up` statement. Then run the migration again.

Comment: Use php artisan migrate:refresh or manually delete your database and create new database then write php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the following.
http://laravelbook.com/laravel-migrations-managing-databases/

I expect you didn't create the migration tracking table.

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

The Laravel instructions can be unclear on things, you just need to work through it.

Answer (score 0):

it is not bug migration system not like external edits

use

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
//or
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Comment: @T.Smith also you can use [iseed](https://github.com/orangehill/iseed) create seeders  based on current database

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Laravel 5.5, use

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```